# Set default line style cycler in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can set a default color cycle for lines in matplotlib using `matplotlib.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = my_color_list`, but I can't figure out how to do the same thing with line styles (i.e. `'-','--','-.',':'`). I know I can set this using something like

```
linecycler = itertools.cycle(lines)
for i in range(n):
    plt.plot(x[i],y[i],next(linecycler))
```

but I'd like to be able to do something more like the color cycle thing so I don't have to make a new cycler every time I want to plot. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're running matplotlib 1.5 or greater, then you can introduce cyclers for all plot properties in `rcParam` using `axes.prop_cycle` (and `axes.color_cycle` was deprecated in favor of `axes.prop_cycle`). In short, you should be able to do something along these lines:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler
plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=(cycler('color', ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y']) +
                           cycler('linestyle', ['-', '--', ':', '-.'])))
```

See [this example](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/examples/color/color_cycle_demo.py) and [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/cycler/) for details.